# How to set a proxy to a public maven repository is read-only mode

Tags: maven, nexus

I want to setup a development environment that allows reusing some artifacts from public Maven repositories like Maven Central, Code Haus. Specifically, I like the concept of transitive dependencies.
In our company, our production network **cannot** export any data outside, but we can push data inside. We already have some gateways to copy file from the outside into our network. Therefore, I could use this to copy the required packages manually but we would miss the power of maven. In our case, the perfect solution would be to be able to get data **from** public repository but be forbidden to deploy to the external repo.
So I would like to have your expert view on this problem.
We can use various means, as long as the capability to export data outside our network is guarantee:

- External packages are created on a disk area that is read-only from production servers.
- Some HTTP requests are filtered.
- Using a repository manager, as Nexus.

In the repository management guide, Nexus talks about this possibility (http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-manage-repo.html). I would like a confirmation from you guys about how secure it is. Specifically, this has to be updated only by the IT manager.

Regards,
Loïc.

Comment: Why would you like to export data `outside` what ever this means? Do you like to populate your artifacts to Maven Central or make it available via Internet ?

Comment: I actually need to setup a solution that ensures that there are no means to upload any data to external servers. This implies I must disable maven capabilities to deploy artifacts on external repositories.

Comment: I assume you have already a proxy internally which need authentication so this is the barrier which prevents from deploying things into the outside. Furthermore you can configuration maven via settings.xml to consume artifacts only via nexus. CI servers as well. To deploy on an external repository you need credentials so someone who does must have appropriate credentials.

Comment: Yes, we have a good deal of flexibility to setup the access control policy. I just need to be clear and specific enough to expose the problem and the solution to the IT support guy. Fortunately, he is a smart guy.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely feasible and a common setup with Nexus. Here are the steps roughly.

- Lock all developers and CI server inside the network disallowing direct access to outside servers
- Setup Nexus to proxy external repositories like Central as desired
- Allow Nexus to reach to those external repositories via the proxy
- Configure developers and CI server machines to access Nexus to get the dependencies (and transitive dependencies) as desired

Optionally you can also

- Configure CI servers to deploy any internal packages to Nexus
- Configure deployment tools to get components for deployment from Nexus

Also note this can be done via different repository formats and toolchains. The common one is Maven, but Nexus also supports NPM, Nuget, Rubygems, sites, YUM and others.

And if you want to make some of your packages in Nexus available to the outside you can configure this as well following multiple options.

Also note that a proxy repository is by definition read only in terms of deployments to it directly. Thats what a hosted repository is for...

Comment: Hi Manfred,  Thanks a lot for the heads-up. This will be very useful to drive my investigations.